# Get text from "data" tag and load it with animation

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have unordered list with 'data-text' tag on each element, and also empty "p" tag. 
I use click event on each item and get text from data-text tag to load in this p tag with animation.

But the problem is that animation works only for first time, when click on the other element the text loads without animation.

Demo: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fp0xywzk/1/)

```js
$("ul.list > .list-item").each(function() {
  $(this).click(function() {
    $(".text-here").text($(this).data('text')).animate({
      opacity: '1',
      top: '0'
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.list-item {
  list-style-tyle: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid red;
  transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
}
.list-item:hover {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
.text-here {
  position: relative;
  top: 40px;
  transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
  padding-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
  <li class="list-item" data-text="1 List Item">1</li>
  <li class="list-item" data-text="2 List Item">2</li>
  <li class="list-item" data-text="3 List Item">3</li>
  <li class="list-item" data-text="4 List Item">4</li>
</ul>

<p class="text-here"></p>
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: If you can change your HTML markup, you don't need js/jQuery for that

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/fp0xywzk/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would highly suggest using [a CSS3 animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations).

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/9emnbzen/)

In this case, we can use the following keyframe:

```
@keyframes fadeUp {
  0% { top: 40px; opacity: 0; }
}
```

Then add the class `animate` to the element and remove it when the animation ends.

```
.text-here.animate {
  animation: fadeUp 200ms ease-in forwards;
}
```

Full code below:

```js
$('ul.list > .list-item').on('click', function() {
  $('.text-here').addClass('animate').one('animationend', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('animate');
  }).text($(this).data('text'));
});
```

```css
.list-item {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid red;
    transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
}
.list-item:hover {
    background: red;
    color: white;
}
.text-here {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
    opacity: 1;
    padding-left: 40px;
}
.text-here.animate {
  animation: fadeUp 200ms ease-in forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeUp {
  0% { top: 40px; opacity: 0; }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
    <li class="list-item" data-text="1 List Item">1</li>
    <li class="list-item" data-text="2 List Item">2</li>
    <li class="list-item" data-text="3 List Item">3</li>
    <li class="list-item" data-text="4 List Item">4</li>
</ul>
<p class="text-here"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create the `element` each time. so the same `animation` will repeat.

```js
$("ul.list > .list-item").each(function () {
    $(this).click(function () {
        $(".text-here").remove();
        $("<p />").addClass("text-here").insertAfter(".list");
        $(".text-here").text($(this).attr('data-text')).animate({
            opacity: '1',
            top: '0'
        });
    });
});
```

```css
.list-item {
    list-style-tyle: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid red;
    transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
}
.list-item:hover {
    background: red;
    color: white;
}
.text-here {
    position: relative;
    top: 40px;
    transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0;
    padding-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
    <li class="list-item" data-text="1 List Item">1</li>
    <li class="list-item" data-text="2 List Item">2</li>
    <li class="list-item" data-text="3 List Item">3</li>
    <li class="list-item" data-text="4 List Item">4</li>
</ul>
<p class="text-here"></p>
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/fp0xywzk/4/

Answer (score 0):

You have to 'reset' the values your previous animation has set.

So something like this will work:

```
/* 
 * Loop list items, click on it,
 * Get text from data-text tag
 * And set to <p> tag with animation 
*/

$("ul.list > .list-item").each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
       $(".text-here").css('top', '40px');
       $(".text-here").css('opacity', '0');
       $(".text-here").text( $(this).data('text') ).animate({
            opacity: '1',
            top: '0'
       }); 
    });
});
```

This hardcodes the top 40px which you generally do not want to do, but you get the idea.

Comment: I paste this code in jsfiddle, but it doesn't work :(

Comment: the CSS should be applied to `$(".text-here")`, not `$(this)`

Comment: @tweb try it now, i made a fix thanks to the comment A. Wolff made, thanks A. Wolff!

Comment: @Xeli still need a repaint (on chrome at least): http://jsfiddle.net/fp0xywzk/5/  :)

Comment: Haha, nice catch. I suppose it's because the .animate() retrieves the (old) css values before they are updated.